# Symbolic recursive function in Mathematica

Tags: recursion, wolfram-mathematica, symbolic-math

I want to write a recursive function, that evaluates symbolic variables. Here's an example in python:

```
x = ["x0",...]
y = ["y0",...]
def f(n):
    if n<=0:
        return x[0]
    t1 = x[n]
    t2 = y[n]
    r = f(n-1)
    return t1+t2+r
```

How can I reimplement that in Mathematica?

I tried creating variable names manually:

```
toFixedWidth[n_Integer, width_Integer] := \
StringJoin[PadLeft[Characters[ToString[n]], width, "0"]]
make_var[i_] := ToExpression[StringJoin["x", toFixedWidth[i, 2]]]
xtab := Table[{make_var[i]}, {i, 0, 10}]
xtab
```

But it doesn't work:

```
{{make_var[0]}, {make_var[1]}, {make_var[2]}, {make_var[3]}, {
  make_var[4]}, {make_var[5]}, {make_var[6]}, {make_var[7]}, {
  make_var[8]}, {make_var[9]}, {make_var[10]}}
```

I want to see how the expression unfolds (for a more complicated function than in the example), that's why I want all variables to be symbolic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Underscores are reserved for pattern matching (`Blank`).  Try `makevar` instead:

```
toFixedWidth[n_Integer, width_Integer] := 
 StringJoin[PadLeft[Characters[ToString[n]], width, "0"]]
makevar[i_] := ToExpression[StringJoin["x", toFixedWidth[i, 2]]]
xtab := Table[{makevar[i]}, {i, 0, 10}]
xtab
```

> ```
> {{x00}, {x01}, {x02}, {x03}, {x04}, {x05}, {x06}, {x07}, {x08}, {x09}, {x10}}
> ```

Incidentally:

```
Table[Unique["x"], {11}]
```

> ```
> {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11}
> ```

Comment: Cool. Is there a way to make the output of `Table[Unique[]..` look better? x00 is easier to read than x$151

Comment: @user1367401 sorry, that was my mistake, `x` should have been a string.

Comment: @user1367401 by the way, if you have more *Mathematica* questions be sure to join us at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user1367401 You're welcome.  Also, when padding integers as strings to a given length, try this:  `Table[IntegerString[i, 10, 2], {i, 0, 10}]`

Comment: How to "reset" the Unique[]'s function counter? Every call increments it.

Comment: @user1367401 the point of `Unique` is that the symbols are, well, unique. :-)  I don't think you can reset the counter, but you can `Remove` the old symbols. (Be sure you understand what `Remove` does or you'll end up frustrated.)  Try: `list = Table[Unique["x"], {10}]; 
Remove /@ Take[list, 5]; 
Table[Unique["x"], {10}]`